# I'm not understanding why the lines on the plot aren't showing up in R

Tags: r, statistics

Here's my code, everything is running smoothly until I try to create a line 
in the plot. It doesn't give me any error, just nothing showing up!

```
setwd("~/RESEARCH/") 
NHISdata <- read.csv("NHIS Data.csv", header=TRUE) 
attach(NHISdata) 
age = 21 + days_21/365 
#Create a variable centered at 0, for pre and post 

z=ifelse(age>=21,1,0) 
#Create a polynomial in age 

agec=age-21 
agec_sq=agec^2 
agec_cu=agec^3 
#Interact with the post variable 
agec_post=agec*z 
agec_sq_post=agec_sq*z 
agec_cu_post=agec_cu*z 

reg1<- lm(drinks_alcohol ~ z + agec + agec_post) 
reg2<- lm(drinks_alcohol ~ z + agec + agec_sq + agec_post + agec_sq_post) 
reg3<- lm(drinks_alcohol ~ z + agec + agec_sq+ agec_cu + agec_post + 
agec_sq_post + agec_cu_post) 

#z will give us the jump at 21 
summary(reg1) 
summary(reg2) 
summary(reg3) 

pred_rate_linear <- predict(reg1) 
pred_rate_quad <- predict(reg2) 
pred_rate_cubic <- predict(reg3) 

#rate1 <- 
cbind(NHISdata,z,agec,agec_sq,agec_cu,agec_post,agec_sq_post,agec_cu_post,pred_rate_linear,pred_rate_quad,pred_rate_cubic)
#attach(rate1) 
bin7=floor(days_21/7) 
bin14=floor(days_21/14) 
bin30=floor(days_21/30) 
bin100=floor(days_21/100) 
tipsy = data.frame(cbind(days_21,drinks_alcohol,bin7,bin14,bin30,bin100)) 
tipsy = aggregate(NHISdata,by=list(bin30),FUN=mean) 
attach(tipsy) 
par(mfrow=c(2,2), oma=c(0,0,2,0)) 
age = 21 + days_21/365 
plot(x=age, y=drinks_alcohol, xlim=c(19,23), ylim=c(.4,.75), xlab='Age', 
ylab='Drinking Rate', cex = 0.75) 
title(main='Linear Regression') 
sub1 <- subset(tipsy, age>=21) 
sub2 <- subset(tipsy, age<=21) 
lines(sub1$age, sub1$pred_rate_linear) 
lines(sub2$age, sub2$pred_rate_linear) 
summary(age) 
summary(pred_rate_linear) 

plot(x=age, y=drinks_alcohol, xlim=c(19,23), ylim=c(.4,.75), xlab='Age', 
ylab='Drinking Rate', cex = 0.75) 
title(main='W/ Linear Regression Line') 
sub1 <- subset(rate1, age>=21) 
sub2 <- subset(rate1, age<=21) 
lines(sub1$age, sub1$pred_rate_quad, col="red", lwd=3) 
lines(sub2$age, sub2$pred_rate_quad, col="red", lwd=3)
```

Here's the link to the csv file for you to try out. 
http://speedy.sh/BdmP5/NHIS-Data.csv

the summary for age and pred_rate_quad are

```
> summary(age) 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  17.70   20.87   24.00   24.00   27.12   30.85 
> summary(pred_rate_linear) 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.3096  0.6599  0.6631  0.6243  0.6665  0.6701
```

I don't see a problem, why isn't R showing my lines?

Comment: I see you have commented out the `rate1 <-` line, so I'm not even sure why you arent getting an error when you try to subset a data frame that doesn't exist. You should also edit this question to make it *minimal* and reproducible without having to take extra steps to download your data and run the code.

Comment: I agree with rawr completely.  The R code is in a mess and any exact response we give you would be a speculation.  That being said, have you tried using `type ="l"` inside your plot function to force it to use lines?  I have a feeling that the calls you make to `lines()` are erasing your earlier call to `plot()`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `plot()` followed by `lines()` is quite usual and not a problem. The plotting code should work fine if the data is there. Which makes it too bad that OP didn't isolate whether the problem was in data prep or in plotting.

Answer (score 0):

Never use `attach`. **Especially** never use attach when you also use functions like `subset` that use non-standard evaluation (take unquoted column names).

You define `age` as a vector by itself, not as a column of `tipsy`, so it won't be a column of `sub` either. (I haven't run your code, but I'm pretty sure of this.)

Your debugging strategy should be to run each line one-at-a-time and look at the what it is (or at least at its `head()`) in the console. I think, if you had done this, you would have noticed that `sub1` and `sub2` don't have `age` columns. You could do a lot to narrow down where the problem is. Instead of giving use 50 lines of code to produce `sub1` and `sub2`, you should either just give us `dput(head(sub1))` and ask why the plot isn't working---or if `sub1` is missing columns look back to where you think they should be created.